# Strange behavior when using regex to match parentheses in vim

Tags: regex, vim

I'm having some trouble understanding why a regular expression is not working.  I'm searching for the phrase `@Test(groups = {"broken"})`, and I'm not able to find it with this expression:

```
@Test\(groups = {"broken"}\)
```

However, this expression yields results:

```
@Test\(.*groups = {"broken"}\)
```

Why is this happening? I can't see why the first expression would not work, but I understand why the second one does.

Comment: What made you think of trying the 2nd form?

Comment: @LeeMeador  It was a sanity check

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\(` is used for capture in vim since it does not use extended/"magic" regexen by default.  If you want to search for a literal paren, use `(`.

The second expression works because `.*` matches `(`.

Comment: For future people, here is a guide with some more information: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#pattern-atoms

Answer (score 4):

If you want to search for literal text, just prepend `\V` to the search pattern; then, only the backslash has special meaning and must be escaped:

```
/\V@Test(groups = {"broken"})
```

In contrast to most other regular expression dialects, many Vim atoms need to be prefixed with `\` to be non-literal. To make Vim's patterns look more like Perl's, you can prepend `\v`; then, `(...)` do capture grouping (as you've expected), and you need to escape `\(` to match literal parentheses.